# Move first row from a csv to another using php

Tags: php, csv, rows, move

What I need to do is to be able to move the first row from a testdata.csv every time I run the .php to another .csv with the name testdata_new.csv(appending data).

This is an example of data that includes Name, Age, Job

Example data testdata.csv:

> John,32,Scientist
>   Mary,25,Employer
>   Nick,36,Designer
>   Miky,46,Sales
>   Alex,29,Logistics

This is what the .php will do running it:
Cut the first row from testdata.csv(john,32,scientist) and paste it to the new testdata_new.csv under the first row(header) that will always be "Name Age Job".
Save testdata_new.csv and testdata.csv with the remaining rows.

I did some tests but I'm still far away from the solution.

```
<?php 

    $file = "testdata.csv";
    $f = fopen($file, "r");
    $i = 0;

    $file2 = str_replace(".csv", "_new.csv", $file);
    $f2 = fopen($file2,"a");

    while ($i<2) {
        $record = fgetcsv($f);
        foreach($record as $field) {
            echo $field . "<br>";
        }

        $i++;
    }

    fwrite($f2,fread($f, filesize($file)));

    fclose($f);
    fclose($f2);

?>
```

Executing the script will display the first row of the template.csv file
and will produce another file with the name template_new.csv with the following rows:

> Mary,25,Employer
>   Nick,36,Designer
>   Miky,46,Sales
>   Alex,29,Logistics

What I really need to have in the template_new.csv file is only the first row displayed:

> John,32,Scientist

And save again the template.csv without the first row as the idea is to cut and paste the rows, as following:

> Mary,25,Employer
>   Nick,36,Designer
>   Miky,46,Sales
>   Alex,29,Logistics

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: where are you struggling? What does your code, what shout it do?

Comment: what should do the code is mentioned above before the code block. But i cannot make it to move the first row from the .csv. Until now it tkes the first row but it pastes the rest of the rows (except the first one) to the new file.

Comment: Still two open points... where are you struggling? What does your code? I want to help you, but I do not want to copy your code to know what exactly it is doing, so please tell it to us...

Comment: Opens the file testdata.csv tha includes the test data I mentiond above. Then creates and open a  new testdata_new.csv file.
Then read the first row and display it. Next saves data in appending mode to the testdata_new.csv file. The problem is that it saves the remaining data from the testdata.csv file except the first row.

Comment: Now we are getting closer... Please edit your question and include the current state of your script into it. So everyone can see it without the need to read the comments

Comment: I added more info regarding the now status of the script. Thanks for your comments Mischa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as this ;-)

```
$old_file = 'testdata.csv';
$new_file = 'testdata_new.csv';

$file_to_read = file_get_contents($old_file);  // Reading entire file
$lines_to_read = explode("\n", $file_to_read);  // Creating array of lines

if ( $lines_to_read == '' ) die('EOF'); // No data 

$line_to_append = array_shift( $lines_to_read ); // Extracting first line 

$file_to_append = file_get_contents($new_file);  // Reading entire file

if ( substr($file_to_append, -1, 1) != "\n" ) $file_to_append.="\n";  // If new file doesn't ends in new line I add it

// Writing files
file_put_contents($new_file, $file_to_append . $line_to_append . "\n");
file_put_contents($old_file, implode("\n", $lines_to_read));
```

Comment: Hi NetVivius, thanks for your answer! It works perfect the first time I run the script. Cut the first row from old_file and then appends it to the new_file. Exactly what I was searching for. The problem is running the script for a second time. Cut all the remaining rows(not only the first row)  from old_file appending them to the  new_file. I need it to do exactly the same thing(cut only the first row) everytime I run the script. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't ran the script several times? The `array_shift` function only takes the first row of the "old" file. I tested it and it should work. Please check it another time.

Comment: It is really strange. I test it again and again for several times. I delete the the new and old files from the server and I create them again from scratch. I test it one more time 10min ago after your answer. It does always the same. First time all ok, the second time move all the rows from the old to the new file. I run again the script after 5 min from the first time just to avoid timing problems.Nothing, same behaviour...

Comment: Check it now, I fixed a little bug when writing the old file ;-)

Comment: Just PERFECT! Thank you again for your precious help